Как программно прописать миграцию данных из одной базы данных в другую в MS SQL?
На практике в колледже дали задание - создать базы данных, программно прописать миграцию данных из одной базы в другую. Есть две идентичные базы данных, различаются только записи. Каким образом мне произвести эту миграцию? Что значит "программно"?

Какой-нибудь SELECT * INTO <ExternalTable> IN <ExternalDB> FROM <InternalTable> ?

создать базы данных, программно прописать миграцию данных из одной базы в другую А базы данных в одной схеме или в разных? Что значит "программно"? Этот вопрос следовало задавать тому, кто дал задание. Если, конечно, ответ на него не найден в конспектах...

Схемы одинаковые, бд в целом по структуре одинаковые, различаются только данные. Нас отправили в открытое плавание на 10 дней без обратной связи, так что спрашивать не у кого :")))

Схемы одинаковые Вы не поняли вопроса. Пожалуйста, изучите в документации на SQL Server, что такое схема (SCHEMA), чем она отличается от базы данных (DATABASE), и почему схему нельзя путать со списком таблиц базы данных и структурой этих таблиц.
